# How to create a second "ActionListener"

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am trying to create a program that would act somewhat like the calculator Windows provides within the OS but, I am struggling to figure out how I am supposed to add a second action listener that would recognize the second click. Also, how would I set it to only take in the first button clicked.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JButton b0 = new JButton("0");
JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
JButton b9 = new JButton("9");
int a;
public Calculator(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Calculator");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(500,300);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.add(p);
    p.add(b0);
    p.add(b1);
    p.add(b2);
    p.add(b3);
    p.add(b4);
    p.add(b5);
    p.add(b6);
    p.add(b7);
    p.add(b8);
    p.add(b9);
    b0.addActionListener(this);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    b4.addActionListener(this);
    b5.addActionListener(this);
    b6.addActionListener(this);
    b7.addActionListener(this);
    b8.addActionListener(this);
    b9.addActionListener(this);
    ActionListener d = new ActionListener();
    b0.addActionListener(d);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Calculator();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource() == b0){
        a = 0;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == b1){
        a=1;
        System.out.println(a);

    }
    if (e.getSource() == b2){
        a = 2;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == b3){
        a = 3;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == b4){
        a = 4;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == b5){
        a = 5;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == b6){
        a = 6;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == b7){
        a = 7;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == b8){
        a = 8;
        System.out.println(a);

    }
    if (e.getSource() == b9){
        a = 9;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For your number buttons, you don't need a second ActionListener. You need to use arrays here, and rather than using a second listener, make the current one smarter.

Comment: Some notes: 1) The frame should made visible *after* you add all your components to it. 2) Instead of set a fixed size to the frame you should call `pack()` method right before calling `setVisible(true)` 3) Since it is supposed to be a calculator, you may want to try `GridLayout` intead of `FolwLayout` to make the buttons grid.

Comment: In your case, you don't need a second action listener.  For those that do, you create separate classes that implement ActionListener.  Don't try to do everything in one class.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

If you want the response to a button press to be different depending on if the button is pressed first or second, the key is not to give it two ActionListeners, but rather to give it one **smart** ActionListener. For instance, if you give the ActionListener a boolean `firstPress` variable, you can set it and check it inside of the ActionListener and change the listener's behavior depending on the state of this variable. For example if you want the listener to accept two number buttons and then add them up, you could do something like:

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
  private int firstNumber;
  private boolean firstClick = true;

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // here actionCommand is the button's text
     String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
     int number = Integer.parseInt(actionCommand);

     if (firstClick) {
        firstNumber = number; // set the firstNumber
        System.out.println("First Number is: " + firstNumber);
     } else {
        int secondNumber = number; //set secondNumber
        int sum = firstNumber + secondNumber; // add them
        System.out.println("Second Number is: " + secondNumber);
        System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
     }

     firstClick = !firstClick; // toggle firstClick
  };
}
```

For example,

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Calc2 extends JPanel {

   private static final int MAX = 10;

   public Calc2() {
      ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
         String text = String.valueOf(i);
         JButton button = new JButton(text);
         button.addActionListener(buttonListener);
         add(button);
      }
   }

   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
      private int firstNumber;
      private boolean firstClick = true;

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // here actionCommand is the button's text
         String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
         int number = Integer.parseInt(actionCommand);

         if (firstClick) {
            firstNumber = number;
            System.out.println("First Number is: " + firstNumber);
         } else {
            int secondNumber = number;
            int sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            System.out.println("Second Number is: " + secondNumber);
            System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
         }

         firstClick = !firstClick; // toggle firstClick
      };
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Calc2 mainPanel = new Calc2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calc2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```